# Can I pass a reference type to a template to specify following non-type template parameters' types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, non-type

Consider an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, T>
struct has_duplicates_info { };

template <class T, T...>
struct has_duplicates;

template <class T, T First, T... Others>
struct has_duplicates<T, First, Others...>:
          has_duplicates<T, Others...>,
          has_duplicates_info<T, First> {
   static constexpr bool value =
      std::is_base_of<has_duplicates_info<T, First>, has_duplicates<T, Others...>>::value
        || has_duplicates<T, Others...>::value;
};

template <class T, T Last>
struct has_duplicates<T, Last>: has_duplicates_info<T, Last>, std::false_type { };

int a, b;

int main() {
   static_assert(!has_duplicates<int, 0, 1, 2>::value, "has_duplicates<int, 0, 1, 2>::value");
   static_assert(has_duplicates<int, 1, 2, 2, 3>::value, "!has_duplicates<int, 1, 2, 2, 3>::value");
   static_assert(has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value, "!has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value");
}
```

This compiles fine with clang but not with gcc. The problem is in a line:

```
static_assert(has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value, "has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value");
```

where compiler suggests that `has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>` is an incomplete type:

> ```
> has_duplicates.cc:26:18: error: incomplete type ‘has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>’ used in nested name specifier
>     static_assert(has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value, "has_duplicates<int&, a, a, b>::value");
>                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

So... which compiler is right?

**Edit:**

To clarify I am **not** trying to check if the runtime values behind variables passed to `has_duplicates` contains duplicates only if there are duplicated references passed to this trait... E.g. the code below compiles successfully in both gcc and clang:

```
template <int &X>
struct a { };

int b;

int main() {
   a<b> c;
}
```

Comment: You can not use a runtime value as template parameter (clang is buggy here)

Comment: @DieterLücking I am not using runtime value only the reference to variable - according to language specification you can use reference to a static variable as a template parameter just like in case of reference to a function... Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's definitely a bug in gcc. You're nearly correct in your diagnosis of the nature of the bug, but it's not that gcc doesn't accept reference-type non-type template parameters, it's rather that gcc fails to *recognise* reference-type non-type template parameters as a class template partial specialization where the reference type is a previous template parameter:

```
template<int, class T, T> struct S;  // #1
template<class T, T A> struct S<0, T, A> {};  // #2
int i;
S<0, int&, i> s;  // #3 error: aggregate 'S<0, int&, i> s' has incomplete type
```

`#2` is a perfectly legitimate partial specialization of `#1` and should be matched by the instantiation `#3`, per [temp.class.spec.match] and [temp.deduct].

Fortunately, there's a simple workaround, which is to provide a further partial specialization for reference types:

```
template<class R, R& A> struct S<0, R&, A> {};
```

A *correct* compiler like clang will also be fine with this.

In your case the further partial specializations would be:

```
template <class R, R& First, R&... Others>
struct has_duplicates<R&, First, Others...> // ...
template <class R, R& Last>
struct has_duplicates<R&, Last> // ...
```

Comment: @W.F. couldn't find anything; filed https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77435